# Best way to implement to do list in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement To do list in android. I want to do something like when its is done and checked it should be scratch and dimmed. But there is no direct control like the Image View or the Button for this purpose. I guess I need to create a custom view. But what should I include in it? Can somebody describe me the steps to follow. A sample code will be even more helpful. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need a checkbox and change the font color to a light grey with strikethrough.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for delay. I was away for some work. Can you please tell me how to do the strikethrough you mentioned. I do not see a direct property for checkbox. Thank you.